# How can I use babel-polyfill for multiple separated entries / outputs?

Tags: javascript, webpack, babeljs, babel-polyfill

I have this in my `webpack.config.js` to create two different outputs from two sources:

```
module.exports = {
  entry: {
    'dist/index.js': ['babel-polyfill', './src/Component.jsx'],
    'example/bundle.js': ['babel-polyfill', './src/Page.jsx'],
  },
  output: {
    path: './',
    filename: '[name]',
  },
  ...
```

Compiling it with *webpack* works just fine, but if I load `index.js` in a browser I get this error:

> Uncaught Error: only one instance of babel-polyfill is allowed

I need *babel-polyfill* for both outputs. What can I do?

Comment: Could you clarify why specifically you want it in both entry points? It's pretty large, you really don't want to be loading it twice without a really good reason.

Comment: Sure! I want to create a react component as a npm package (*dist/index.js*). In order to develop the component in isolation, I created a small page (*example/bundle.js*), which loads the component and displays the result. When I work on the component I can see the results in the browser on that little page. The overhead wouldn't be a problem because the code remains small in most cases.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When developing a library (as opposed to an application), the Babel team does not recommend including `babel-polyfill` in your library. We recommend either:

1. Assume the ES6 globals are present, thus you'd instruct your library users to load `babel-polyfill` in their own codebase.
2. Use `babel-runtime` by enabling `babel-plugin-transform-runtime`, which attempts to analyze your code to figure out what ES6 library functionality you are using, then rewrites the code to load the polyfilled logic from `babel-runtime` instead of from the global scope. One downside of this approach is that it has no way to polyfill new `.prototype` methods like `Array.prototype.find` since it can't know if `foo.find` is an array.

So my recommendation would be to remove `babel-polyfill` from your `dist/index.js` bundle entirely.

Comment: What option do you recommend? Also if I want to load it independently, how would you recommend to do it?

Comment: To make a js file with just `import "babel-polyfill";` and add its entry and load it first?

Answer (score 0):

Use idempotent-babel-polyfill

```
import 'idempotent-babel-polyfill';
```

https://github.com/codejamninja/idempotent-babel-polyfill